# Which jniLibs do you need for OpenCV on Android?

Tags: android, opencv

I have an android app with opencv features. It's working but the generated apk is pretty big. I wonder if all jniLibs that I include are really necessary for android? MinSDK is 15 if that is important somehow.

Here is a list of the includes jniLibs:

[image]

Comment: I think the JNI Libs are used by android OS based on your mobile processor. so it's needed.

Comment: Nevertheless there are lots of apps in the appstore that use OpenCV and don't have 100 mb apk size.

Comment: See this link , it may be useful for you http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html

Comment: for my project, I included only armeabi-v7a & arm64-v8a

Comment: @CuongNguyen is your project installed on lots of different devices?